# How to make name of activity variable in Java for android programming?

Tags: java, android, listener

In the application, sometimes, the entire code is same except the name of the activity for the next process.
If there is a way to make the name of the activity string variable, then what the programmer only has to do would be changeing the string name.

For example,

```
private static string ActivityName = "com.brbr.brbr.ListenerActivity";
..
ActivityName.listener = new onfunctionnameListener(){
..
```

though this isn't working.

The currently working code goes like this.

```
    ..
    ListenerActivity.listener = new onfunctionnameListener(){
    ..
```

Let's share the opinions toward the java, string concept :)

Comment: OMG ... how can it work ... >_<

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, I would propose to use a parent class that already implements all your methods, e.g. `ActivityForm`.

After this class could after that be extended by your other activities and so you do just have to override the methods where the code differs.

A tutorial and a bit more information can be fount [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).